# Is ntpd working?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I'm running `ntpd` on my machine, but I'm not sure if it is working correctly. How can I query `ntpd` to determine whether it has successfully connected to time servers and that my kernel time is synchronized?

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to determine whether `ntpd` is working:

1. Use `ntpq -p` (or `ntpq -pn` to save time by skipping DNS lookups).

   This is what it looks like when NTP is working:

   ```
   host-a ~ # ntpq -p
        remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
   ==============================================================================
    0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
   +mail.masters-of 144.76.76.107    3 u  975 1024  377   13.731   -0.737   2.552
   +ntp2.hetzner.de 124.216.164.14   2 u  232 1024  377   15.914   -0.650   0.854
   +rondra.lf-net.o 237.17.204.95    2 u 1020 1024  377   13.751   -0.557   4.292
   -funky.f5s.de    131.188.3.222    2 u  480 1024  377   15.730    2.082   4.377
   +stratum2-3.NTP. 129.70.137.82    2 u  742 1024  377   19.785   -0.366   7.498
   *mail.klausen.dk 193.79.237.14    2 u  173 1024  377   14.383   -0.513   2.066
   ```

   It'll list the actual peers it has connected to; `*` indicates the the source you are synchronized to. More information on the output is available in the [NTP docs](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/TroubleshootingNTP#Section_9.4.).

   This is what it looks like when it's not:

   ```
   host-b ~ # ntpq -p
        remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
   ==============================================================================
    0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
    3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
   ```

   Note that there aren't any actual peers listed, which usually indicates that `ntpd` wasn't able to connect to any, probably because a firewall prevented the connections.

   `ntpq -p` isn't well-suited for scripted checks because the output has to be parsed, and while it's speed (30ms for a single call) isn't bad, there are faster ways which I'm going to discuss later on.
2. If you're using `systemd`, you can use `timedatectl status`.

   This is what it looks like when NTP is working (note the `System clock synchronized: yes`):

   ```
   host-a ~ # timedatectl status 
                  Local time: Do 2021-04-22 13:29:20 CEST
              Universal time: Do 2021-04-22 11:29:20 UTC
                    RTC time: Do 2021-04-22 11:29:21
                   Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
   System clock synchronized: yes
                 NTP service: inactive
             RTC in local TZ: no
   ```

   This is what it looks like when it's not (note the `System clock synchronized: no`):

   ```
   host-b ~ # timedatectl status
                  Local time: Do 2021-04-22 13:29:53 CEST
              Universal time: Do 2021-04-22 11:29:53 UTC
                    RTC time: Do 2021-04-22 11:29:42
                   Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
   System clock synchronized: no
                 NTP service: inactive
             RTC in local TZ: no
   ```

   (`NTP service` refers to `systemd-timesyncd`, `systemd`'s own NTP client. It shouldn't be running while `ntpd` is installed, so the `no` is to be expected here.)

   `timedatectl status` queries `systemd-timedated` which is only started on demand, which leads to a small performance penalty of ~100ms on the first call; further calls take about ~12ms.

   `systemd-timedated` in turn uses the `adjtimex(2)` syscall to query the kernel; if `adjtimex(2)` returns a status with the `STA_UNSYNC` bit set, the clock isn't synchronized. This means that `timedatectl` isn't actually talking to `ntpd`, but instead queries a bit stored in the kernel which NTP services like `ntpd` will update whenever the synchronization status changes.

   `timedatectl status` is well-suited for scripting, because you can query the relevant property directly:

   ```
   host-a ~ # timedatectl show -p NTPSynchronized --value                          
   yes
   host-b ~ # timedatectl show -p NTPSynchronized --value
   no
   ```
3. Use `adjtimex(2)` directly:

   This is the least user-friendly approach, but the fastest one for scripting. `busybox` as provided by Debian buster has a `adjtimex` applet that serves as a simple wrapper around the `adjtimex(2)` syscall.

   This is what it looks like when NTP is working:

   ```
   host-a ~ # busybox adjtimex
       mode:         0
   -o  offset:       -570098 us
   -f  freq.adjust:  857283 (65536 = 1ppm)
       maxerror:     478704
       esterror:     302
       status:       8193 (PLL)
   -p  timeconstant: 10
       precision:    1 us
       tolerance:    32768000
   -t  tick:         10000 us
       time.tv_sec:  1619092119
       time.tv_usec: 60467600
       return value: 0 (clock synchronized)
   ```

   This is what it looks like when it's not (note the `UNSYNC` in the `status` line, and the ):

   ```
   host-b ~ # busybox adjtimex
       mode:         0
   -o  offset:       0 us
   -f  freq.adjust:  2126708 (65536 = 1ppm)
       maxerror:     16000000
       esterror:     16000000
       status:       16449 (PLL | UNSYNC)
   -p  timeconstant: 7
       precision:    1 us
       tolerance:    32768000
   -t  tick:         10000 us
       time.tv_sec:  1619091984
       time.tv_usec: 307119
       return value: 5 (clock not synchronized)
   ```

   Unfortunately `busybox adjtimex` doesn't seem to provide a way to print only a certain field, and the return value is only printed, not actually returned. This means that for scripting, you're going to have to parse the output (e.g. `busybox adjtimex | grep -q UNSYNC`). On the other hand, it compensates for this by being extremely fast - only 0.5ms!

Comment: Note that you can specify which service `timedatectl` sees as the "NTP service:" by setting the `SYSTEMD_TIMEDATED_NTP_SERVICES` environment variable for `systemd-timedated.service`. For example, if you set the variable as `SYSTEMD_TIMEDATED_NTP_SERVICES=chronyd.service:ntpd.service` then timedated (and also timedatectl) will look for `chronyd.service` and then `ntpd.service`. Old versions of `systemd` might not include this functionality.